# Set if conditional inside a lambda function depending on whether a value captured using regex is None or ""

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, lambda, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text = 'desde el 2022_-_12_-_10 corrimos juntas hasta el 11° nivel de aquella montaña hasta el 2022_-_12_-_13' #example 1
#input_text = 'desde el 2022_-_11_-_10 18:30 pm hasta el 2022_-_12_-_01 21:00 hs' #example 2

#text in the middle associated with the date range...
some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*)[^;])*" #but cannot contain ";", ".\s*"

identificate_hours = r"(?:a\s*las|a\s*la|)\s*(?:\(|)\s*(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s*(?:(am)|(pm)|)\s*(?:\)|)" #no acepta que no se le indicase el 'am' o el 'pm'

date_format = r"(?:\(|)\s*(\d*)_-_(\d{2})_-_(\d{2})\s*(?:\)|)"

some_text_limiters = [r",\s*hasta", r"hasta", r"al", r"a "]


for some_text_limiter in some_text_limiters:

    identification_re_0 = r"(?:(?<=\s)|^)(?:desde\s*el|desde|del|de\s*el|de\s*la|de |)\s*(?:día|dia|fecha|)\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de |)\s*" + date_format + r"\s*(?:" + identificate_hours + r"|)\s*(?:\)|)\s*(" + some_text + r")\s*" + some_text_limiter + r"\s*(?:el|la|)\s*(?:fecha|d[íi]a|)\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de|)\s*" + date_format + r"\s*(?:" + identificate_hours + r"|)\s*(?:\)|)"

    input_text = re.sub(identification_re_0,
                        lambda m: if(r"{m[1]}" == None or r"{m[1]}" == " " or r"{m[1]}" == "") : (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))").replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "(") else : (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))({m[8]})").replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "("),
                        input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

print(repr(input_text))
```

I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` whis this lambda `lambda m: if(r"{m[8]}" == None or r"{m[8]}" == " " or r"{m[8]}" == "") : (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))").replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "(") else : (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))({m[8]})").replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "(")`

How should I evaluate the conditions inside the lambda function housed inside the parameter of the `re.sub()` function?

`lambda m: if(r"{m[8]}" == None or r"{m[8]}" == " " or r"{m[8]}" == "") :    else:`

All the evaluation of the conditional depends on `"{m[8]}"`, and the outputs should be like the following

```
#for example 1, where {m[8]} is not None
'(2022_-_12_-_(10(00:00 am)_--_2022_-_12_-_(13(00:00 am)))(corrimos juntas hasta el 11° nivel de aquella montaña)'

#for example 2, where {m[8]} is None, and remove the last ()
'(2022_-_11_-_(10(18:30 pm)_--_2022_-_12_-_(01(21:00 am)))()hs' #wrong output
'(2022_-_11_-_(10(18:30 pm)_--_2022_-_12_-_(01(21:00 am)))hs' #correct output
```

---

Edit question with the error:

```py
def sub_rule(m):
    res_true = f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))"

    # ternary expression is general, not limited to lambdas
    return (
        res_true.replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "(")
        if (r"{m[8]}" == None or r"{m[8]}" == " " or r"{m[8]}" == "") 
        else 
        (res_true + f"({m[8]})").replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "(")
        )


some_text_limiters = [r",\s*hasta", r"hasta", r"al", r"a "]

for some_text_limiter in some_text_limiters:

    identification_re_0 = r"(?:(?<=\s)|^)(?:desde\s*el|desde|del|de\s*el|de\s*la|de |)\s*(?:día|dia|fecha|)\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de |)\s*" + date_format + r"\s*(?:" + identificate_hours + r"|)\s*(?:\)|)\s*(" + some_text + r")\s*" + some_text_limiter + r"\s*(?:el|la|)\s*(?:fecha|d[íi]a|)\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de|)\s*" + date_format + r"\s*(?:" + identificate_hours + r"|)\s*(?:\)|)"

    input_text = re.sub(identification_re_0,
                        sub_rule,
                        input_text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

And the wrong output:

```
'(2022_-_12_-_(10(00:00 am)_--_2022_-_12_-_(13(00:00 am)))()'
```

And the correct ouput in example 2:

```
'(2022_-_12_-_(10(00:00 am)_--_2022_-_12_-_(13(00:00 am)))'
```

---

EDIT 2: I have managed to perform the conditional, although not within the same lambda

```
def remove_or_not_parentheses_from_middle_text(m):

    print(repr(m[8]))

    if ( str(m[8]) == None or str(m[8]) == " " or str(m[8]) == ""): res_true = (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))").replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "(")
    else: res_true = (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))({m[8]})").replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "(")

    return res_true
```

Comment: You can't include an `if` *statement* inside a lambda *expression*. If you can't fit the lambda expression comfortably on one line, replace it with a function defined by a `def` statement. One is not more efficient than the other; both create values of type `function`. The difference is whether you "clutter" the current scope with a name you won't use more than once.

Comment: Plus, your lambda expression has to be evaluated on every loop iteration, but it doesn't change from one to the next. Define it *once* with a `def` statement before the loop and reuse the same function for each call to `re.sub`.

Comment: @chepner You are right, anyway, it is preferable that it be in a single line with a lambda function, however, you are right and it may be more convenient to do it in a separate function

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your output, [see](https://onlinegdb.com/OGkZPIQOq)

Comment: @cards that's because you use example 1, that is `input_text = 'from 2022_-_12_-_10 we ran together up to the 11th level of that mountain until 2022_-_12_-_13' #example 1` and the error is with example 2 `input_text = 'desde el 2022_-_11_-_10 18:30 pm hasta el 2022_-_12_-_01 21:00 hs' #example 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *ternary expression* of a conditional, `(do) if (condition) else (do other)`.

```
f = lambda x: True if x > 0 else False
print(f(10))
# True
```

Nesting is also possible

```
g = lambda x: '-' if x < 0 else '+' if x < 10 else '+ but more than 10'
print(g(5))
# +
```

Hint: split long expressions into multiple lines using `(` and `)`, fir ex like this

```
lambda m: (
        f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))")
       .replace(" )", ")")
       .replace("( ", "(")
   )
   if (r"{m[1]}" == None or r"{m[1]}" == " " or r"{m[1]}" == "") 
   else (
       f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))({m[8]})")
      .replace(" )", ")")
      .replace("( ", "(")
   )
```

---

In this case a `lambda` function is not a good choice:

- as mentioned by *chepner* the function depends only on the `match` object and not on the iterations variables
- a *clean* variable initialization cannot be done with `lambda` and here could be useful because the outcome of each conditional branch is almost similar

```
# outside the loop

def sub_rule(m):
    res_true = f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_({m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'})_--_{m[9]}_-_{m[10]}_-_({m[11]}({m[12] or '00'}:{m[13] or '00'} {m[14] or m[15] or 'am'})))"

    # ternary expression is general, not limited to lambdas
    return (
        res_true.replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "(")
        if (r"{m[1]}" == None or r"{m[1]}" == " " or r"{m[1]}" == "") 
        else 
        (res_true + f"({m[8]})").replace(" )", ")").replace("( ", "(")
        )
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives me wrong output `'(2022_-_12_-_(10(00:00 am)_--_2022_-_12_-_(13(00:00 am)))({m[8]})'` ; There I edited the question with the new code

Comment: Ah sorry! I forgot the string format prefix. It should be `res_true + f"({m[8]})")`

Comment: I modify `if (r"{m[1]}" == None or r"{m[1]}" == " " or r"{m[1]}" == "") ` to  `if (r"{m[8]}" == None or r"{m[8]}" == " " or r"{m[8]}" == "") `, but it still gives wrong output with **example 2**,  `'(2022_-_11_-_(10(18:30 pm)_--_2022_-_12_-_(01(21:00 am)))()hs'`

Comment: I did not change the logic of the program but just rephrase the conditional in the lambda. I cannot reproduce your ouput. Instead I get `(2022_-_12_-_(10(00:00 am)_--_2022_-_12_-_(13(00:00 am)))(corrimos juntas hasta el 11° nivel de aquella montaña)`

Comment: with example 2 I had the problem, which is when m[8] is equal to None

Comment: Sorry, but this is another question. I don't know what your code does. Hint: comparison with `None` should be done like `var is None` and not with `==`.  In the code there is (maybe!) some confusion with the comparison with `None`. What is `r"{m[1]}" == None`? `r"{m[1]}"` returns a string and not a `None`

Comment: The code works well, the only problem is that it does not enter in to the if condition in the example 2. In the example 1 work weel because this enter in to the else condition

Comment: 1. which condition should example 2 trigger? 2. try to remove the condition `r"{m[1]}" == None` and check if does change the output

Comment: I edit the question with the code and the correct and the wrong ouút in example 2

Comment: I tried some more attempts but to understand the full logic of the program is too much for me... working with so many groups and recursive substitution just take too much time and also take me far from the original question. I suggest you to set up a minimal working example, it could also be useful for you to identify the problem

Comment: Thank you very much anyway for the help, anyway the regex logic works fine, what doesn't work is the conditional log inside the lambda function. Now add an edit where I put how the modifier function should be, although it is giving me SybtaxError in the conditionals

Comment: Based on your answer I have built the function with the conditionals, although it is not a lambda function it works quite well. Really thank you very much for answering.